# What is the method of sending a message and waiting on an api response in Studio Flow?

Tags: sms

We have a service where we have our service partners send us a number of photos while in a Studio Flow. The photos need to be checked by one of our support team so that we can make a (human) decision and move one way or another in the Flow.

We have the full flow working and operational and syncing with our application so that the photos submitted are shown in our app in near real-time.

I now need to inject a "pause" in proceedings while a member of our staff is alerted to the receipt of the media and press an approve/deny button, *and this is where we are stuck.*

**How do we send a message to say "We are checking the photos" and pause until the API call is returned** with a proceed: true/false decision? If we put a 'send and wait for reply' widget in place we need a response from them, right? And if I don't wait on a reply the flow continues on and is unaware we are waiting for the API?